# Unity multitouch cant reach its methods

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, touchscreen

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrCUO46jcxk&t=156s) tutorial and basically I did everything same. However I can't reach methods inside the testTouch class. Here is TouchInput class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class touchInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LayerMask touchInputMask;
    private List<GameObject> touchList = new List<GameObject>();
    private GameObject[] touchesOld;
    private RaycastHit hit;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

#if UNITY_EDITOR
```

//same things for unity editor as be shown in tutorial
#endif

```
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            touchesOld = new GameObject[touchList.Count];
            touchList.CopyTo(touchesOld);
            touchList.Clear();
            foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
            {
                Ray ray = GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);


                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, touchInputMask))
                {
                    GameObject recepient = hit.transform.gameObject;
                    touchList.Add(recepient);

                    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                    {
                        recepient.SendMessage("OnTouchDown", hit.point, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                    }

                    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                    {
                        recepient.SendMessage("OnTouchUp", hit.point, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                    }

                    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
                    {
                        recepient.SendMessage("OnTouchStay", hit.point, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                    }

                    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)
                    {
                        recepient.SendMessage("OnTouchExit", hit.point, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (GameObject g in touchesOld)
            {
                if (!touchList.Contains(g))
                    g.SendMessage("OnTouchExit", hit.point, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is testTouch class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class testTouch : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Color defaultColor;  //set manually in the editor
    public Color selectedColor;  //set manually in the editor
    public Material mat;  

    void Start()
    {
        mat = this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material;
     // mat.color = selectedColor;
    }

    void OnTouchDown()
    {
        mat.color = selectedColor;
        Debug.Log("hello");
    }

    void OnTouchUp()
    {
        mat.color = defaultColor;
        Debug.Log("hello");
    }

    void OnTouchStay()
    {
        mat.color = selectedColor;
        Debug.Log("hello");
    }

    void OnTouchExit()
    {
        mat.color = defaultColor;
        Debug.Log("hello");
    }
```

I don't get any errors and I can't reach those Debug.Logs as well. When I click the 2Dcircle nothing happens.

[image: This is circle object. testTouch is attached to it]

[image: This is main camera. TouchInput is attached to it]

I tried on editor and on my android phone. Both of them is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3D Raycasting (`Physics.Raycast()`) on a 2D colliders does not work.

Replace 2D circle collider with 3D circle collider.

There is no overload of the `Raycast` method that takes a `layerMask` as a third argument.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

You are mistakenly calling another overload of the `Raycast` method.

```
public static bool Raycast(Ray ray, out RaycastHit hitInfo, 
float maxDistance = Mathf.Infinity, int layerMask = DefaultRaycastLayers, 
QueryTriggerInteraction queryTriggerInteraction = QueryTriggerInteraction.UseGlobal);
```